Shape Mismatch Issue in TVP-PVAR Model Implementation
I am reaching out to seek your expertise regarding a persistent issue I have encountered while implementing a Time-Varying Parameter Panel Vector Autoregression (TVP-PVAR) model. I have managed to write a such code and model. Despite several attempts to resolve the problem, I continue to face a shape mismatch error.
Problem Description:
The error message I receive is as follows:
Error at country 0, time 1: Dimension mismatch: array 'cov' is of shape (4, 4), but 'mean' is a vector of length 304.
Likelihood could not be calculated due to an error.

This occurs when using the multivariate_normal.pdf function from the scipy.stats module. The function expects the mean parameter to be a vector with a length equal to the number of rows (or columns) of the covariance matrix R.
Relevant Code Section:
Here is the part of the code where the issue arises:
def likelihood(data, alphas, Phi, Q, R):
    n_countries, n_periods, n_vars = data.shape
    p = Phi.shape[2]
    total_obs = n_countries * n_periods * n_vars

    likelihood = 1
    for i in range(n_countries):
        for t in range(p, n_periods):
            y_it = data[i, t].ravel()
            y_hat = alphas[i] + np.sum([np.dot(data[i, t-j], Phi[i, j-1]) for j in range(1, p+1)], axis=0)
            y_hat_flat = y_hat.ravel()  # Flatten y_hat for compatibility

            try:
                likelihood *= multivariate_normal.pdf(y_it, mean=y_hat_flat, cov=R)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Error at country {i}, time {t}: {e}")
                return None

    return likelihood

> 
> ```

Despite ensuring that y_it and y_hat are flattened to 1D vectors, the mismatch persists. The current definition of R is as follows:

R = np.eye(n_vars)  # Observation equation covariance matrix




Here, R is defined as the covariance matrix for the observation equation. Given that n_vars is 4, R is a 4x4 identity matrix.
Steps Taken to Resolve the Issue:

Flattened y_it and y_hat: Reshaped both y_it and y_hat to 1D vectors using .ravel().

Defined Compatible Shape for R: Attempted to ensure R had a compatible shape with the length of y_hat.ravel(). Originally set R to np.eye(n_vars), but considering the length of y_hat.ravel() is 304, a larger identity matrix was also tested.

Print Statements for Debugging: Added print statements to verify shapes of y_it, y_hat, and R.


Despite these efforts, the shape mismatch error persists. I suspect there might be a fundamental issue with the way R is being defined or used in the context of the likelihood calculation. I need to have the likelihood calculation explicitly calculated in the code.
Request for Assistance:*
I have several blocks of variables for the model. For this example, I use 4 variables, reaching at a model of 28 variables. All variables are endogenous.
Could you please provide guidance on how to correctly define and use the covariance matrix R in this context? Any insights or suggestions on resolving the shape mismatch would be greatly appreciated.

Can you fix the indentation in your code?

Fixed. I can provide more details if needed. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!
